# There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, rubygems, bundle

So i'm following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, and have changed my Gemfile to look as such: (only to get "There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue." after having run Bundle install). Any ideas? thanks

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an end at:

```
#gem 'sqlite3'
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
```

Comment: Thanks! That has helped me to solve the issue. Although the new error message is "Could not find gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0' in the gems available on this machine."

Comment: @user1975127 that's another question, why don't you ask it as a SO question, or preferably check first if there's a slmilar question already answered here?

Comment: The 2.0.0 version of jquery-rails got yanked from RubyGems; you could try changing '2.0.0' to a newer version (current is '2.2.0').